# How to make different width of some tabs in qtabwidget?

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, qtabwidget

In my project there is a QTabWidget with 5 tabs, using styleSheet I changed style of whole widget, but some tabs become small for text in them. How to make individual width for some tabs?
[image]

As you can see, first 3 tabs have normal width, but last 2 are too small for text in them.
Stylesheet:

```
QTabWidget::pane
{               
    background-color: rgb(212, 234, 255);
    border: 1px solid; /*граница*/
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
QTabWidget::tab-bar
{   
    left: 10px; /*перемещение кнопок вкладок*/
    width: 650px;
}
QTabBar::tab
{
    font: 75 11pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, 
                                stop:0 rgba(53, 92, 88, 255), 
                                stop:1 rgba(45, 143, 132, 255));
                                
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    min-width: 5px;
    padding: 6px;   
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
QTabBar::tab:selected, 
QTabBar::tab:hover
{
    background-color: rgb(63, 171, 160);
}
QTabBar::tab:!selected
{
    margin-top: 5px
}
QTabBar::tab:selected
{
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, 
                                stop:0 rgba(53, 92, 88, 255), 
                                stop:1  rgb(58, 207, 192));
}
```

Additional info:
Im not changing .ui or .py files of UI;
For creating UI I using QtDesigner;
All logic code is in separate file, where I importing UI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Move the font properties to the main `QTabBar` type selector:

```css
QTabBar {
    font: 75 11pt "MS Shell Dlg 2";
    font-weight: bold;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.502, y1:1, x2:0.493, y2:0, 
                                stop:0 rgba(53, 92, 88, 255), 
                                stop:1 rgba(45, 143, 132, 255));
    ...
```

### Explanation

The issue is caused by the fact that the font is applied to the `::tab` subcontrol.

While that may make sense, it creates a conceptual problem: QTabBar uses the *widget* font to provide the proper [`tabSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#tabSizeHint) and the QSS rule is based on that too, even if the `::tab` subcontrol has a different font set.

I agree that the implementation is not perfect, but since a subcontrol can also have pseudo states (eg, `:hover` or `:selected`), the result is that the font metrics for a subcontrol are not considered for layout. Simply put: a subcontrol selector must not change the subcontrol size, not even if its font metrics change.

Note that this is quite important: state changes should *never* alter the layout. Imagine what would happen if you set a default bold font for all tabs, but a normal one for the hovered one. If you move the mouse on the right edge of a tab, it will become "hovered", and its font would become "not bold", but that would shorten its width, making the one on its right as hovered; at the next mouse movement, the previously hovered one will be bold again, and it will become hovered again. And so on.

The solution, then, is to properly set the font properties on the QTabBar widget instead (as shown at the beginning of this answer).

In case you really need custom pseudo state based font (for instance, the currently selected tab), then the only remaining solution is to set a custom QTabBar override *both* its `minimumTabSizeHint()` and `tabSizeHint()` and ensure that the tab bar is always expanded in order to include the required space.

Comment: yes, it works 99% like I need, now when last tab is selected, half of first and last letter cut in half.

Comment: @John_2202 Can you please provide a screenshot of that? Also, it would help to have a valid [mre] of your changes (you can use a pastebin in this case) and proper context of your system(s), including your OS, its version, specific Qt version (`QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR`) and even the current `QApplication.style().objectName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the QTabWidget's size policy to "Preferred" in order to allow it to expand to fit its content:

```
myTabWidget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
```

Add the following style sheet to the QTabWidget:

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    width: fit-content;
}
```